# Stop Checkbox event from firing multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am having an issue where I have a GridView's ItemsSource bound to a collection of object.  I also have a column of Check boxes that can be used to select object the user wishes to remove and all related items.  The problem I am having is that when the user selects one item, I get stuck in a loop of the items being continually selected.  Does anyone have an idea on how I can stop the programmatic selection of these check boxes from firing the Checked event.

Property in use:

```
List<MyObject> _localCollection = new List<MyObject>();
List<MyObject> LocalCollection
{
   get { return _localCollection; }
   set
   {
     _localCollection = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("LocalCollection");
   }
}
```

Loose example of XML code:

```
<GridView Name="grdItems">
  <GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
      <CheckBox/>
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
    <!--Column Template-->
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <CheckBox Tag="{Binding ObjID}"
                     IsChecked="{Binding ToRemove, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Checked="SelectRelative" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
```

The "SelectRelative" method looks as follows:

```
 private void SelectRelative(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
      //Get the Object Id we need
      int selectedId = Convert.ToInt32(((CheckBox)sender).Tag);
      //Get all objects that share this ID
      List<MyObjects> objLst = new List<MyObjects>(((IEnumerable<MyObjects>)grdItems.ItemsSource));

      //Clear the local collection property of our items used in the items source
      LocalCollection.Clear();
      //Remove the items source since we are updating it
      grdItems.ItemsSource = null;
      //Go through each item in the list and if the object id's match select them to remove
      foreach(var item in objLst)
      {
        if(item.ObjId == selectedId)
          item.ToRemove = true;
        //Add the object to our property
        LocalCollection.Add(item);
      }
      //Re-establish the item source with our new collection
      grdItems.ItemsSource = LocalCollection;
    }));
 }
```

Comment: (bump) this still is an occurring issue, does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:

 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkboxPaid" Checked="chkboxPaid_Checked" Content="check" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCheckBox}"   IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                          AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: That actually seems to stop the event from firing multiple times, but it also prevents the UI from updating.  I've tried forcing it with grdItems.UpdateLayout();  but that seems to do nothing...interesting but close!!

Comment: So when investigating any errors/exceptions during run time I found the following error message. Could this be because I have the IsChecked bound to a property instead of having the events modify the checked control?

"System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ToRemove; DataItem=null; target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')"